# A footnote about outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

This is the theorem about in Royden's real analysis book. And in the book there is a footnote I am confusing:
[image]

Can anyone help me understanding it with examples~~~

Comment: I don't agree that $\inf\varnothing=+\infty$ is merely a convention.  It is a provable result if one does things carefully.  One place where is useful is this: suppose one defined distance from $a$ to $b$ to be the length of the shortest path from $a$ to $b$; then the distance is $+\infty$ if there is no path from $a$ to $b$, because the minimum of the empty set is $+\infty$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy it depends on the "ambient" set. It is not always the case that it is $+ \infty $. I agree though one could say that since we chose for the "ambient" set  $[0,+ \infty]$ it is this.

Comment: @quid : Generally $\inf\varnothing$ or $\min\varnothing$ should be the biggest of all things, but yes, it depend on what sort of "things" there are. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think we agree. But I still felt like making the remark since especially in the given context I think one will want $\sup  \emptyset $ equal $0$ while in others it would be $-\infty$.

Comment: $\min\emptyset$ is undefined by definition (and by convention) otherwise you must sacrifice $\min X\in X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer measure of $E$ is defined of as the infimum of the following set 
$$\left \{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k) \colon \{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \text{with $E_k\in S$ such that  $E \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ } \right \}$$

Now nothing guarantees that for some set $E$ there is even one $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ with $E_k\in S$ such that  $E \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$. In this case the set above is empty, and it the outer measure of such an $E$ is then the infimum of the empty set. It is thus necessary to know what the infimum of the empty set would be, and this is what is stated in the footnote.

Comment: Normally $\cup$ is used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$, and $\bigcup$ in things like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: That the infimum of the empty set is the largest member of the ordered set is not merely a convention, but a theorem.

Comment: I changed the formulation avoiding the use of the word convention. I hope this settles this issue.

Comment: one more question : can $E_k$ be $\varnothing$?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one example: $\inf\emptyset=+\infty$. I can explain you the reason. The definition of $\inf$, i.e., greatest lower bound, which is equivalent to $\sup\{x\in\mathbb R:x<y\:\forall y\in\emptyset\}$.  Think about it: this means
$\inf\emptyset=\sup\mathbb R$ and thus $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S := \{ \{x\} \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be covered by countably many elements of $S$.